Getting bad char in struct format when reading byte data
I have binary data with following specification
1 Byte SF-Major
1 Byte SF-Minor
1 Byte SF-Patch
1 Byte SF-Build
2 Byte build (little endian)

I wrote following code to read this data
format_string = (
    'BBBB'
    '<H'
)

parsed_data: bytes = binary_data[:10]
unpacked_data = struct.unpack(format_string, header_data)


on unpacked_data i get error
    unpacked_data = struct.unpack(format_string, header_data)
struct.error: bad char in struct format

this error goes away if i remove < from the format_string OR if i put < as first line in format_string and then followed by remaining lines (H without <)
the problem is that the binary specification says that build is little endian.
what can i do?

struct expects the byte order symbol (<) to be at the beginning of the format string. In your case, you have 5 fields: 4 single byte fields (for which byte order does not matter), and one two-byte field (which is little endian). So you can use the format string <BBBBH:
>>> binary_data = b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x01\xff'
>>> struct.unpack('<BBBBH', binary_data)
(1, 2, 3, 4, 65281)

We can see that this is correct because \x01\xff, as little endian, should be hex 0xFF01, which is what we get.

I am going to update my question with more data. the payload is mix of little endian etc. so not sure if i should put < once in the format string or not.

If you have a new question, then you should create a new question - not change the question after it has been answered.

lol .. its not a new question, its an existing question with specific detailed.
